# Angular2 Routing - keeping state of component when route changes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an application, with views behind routes, I need to be able to continue from the point when the route changed, but after going back, the component is in its initial state.

Is there any way how to keep the state of a component?

Comment: As opposed to providers injected into individual components, the key might be to have app-level providers/services, which is explained a bit here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32807310. As explained in the answer, component-level providers are created every time a route's component is generated. App-level providers (declared inside of `bootstrap`) are created once (see this site for more info: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2). If you come up with a good solution, please post it here.

Answer (score 19):

**update 2**

That's now fixed (Angular 2.3) for the new router by https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13124 which allows to provide a custom reuse strategy.

For an example see also https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/12/02/sticky-routes-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy.aspx

Angular docs https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy

**update 2** This answer is only for a long ago discontinued router version.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards for how to do it in the current router.

**original**

If your components implements [CanReuse](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html) and returns `true` from

```ts
routerCanReuse(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
  return true;
}
```

then the component is kept and reused instead of destroyed and recreated.

Another way is to keep the data in a shared service and fetch them from there when the component is recreated.

Comment: The `CanReuse` link is broken.

Comment: The router where this answer applies is long gone. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards for how to do it in the current router.

Answer (score 3):

There is an open issue on this exact scenario in 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5275

You can use `routerCanReuse` only if the new component and the old component(when you hit the 'back' button) are of the same Component type.

As Günter suggested your only option right now if the Components are of different type is to keep state in a shared service.

Comment: After searching a lot, this worked for me perfecly: 
 https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/12/02/sticky-routes-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy.aspx

Comment: @PhilipEnc How did you make that work? None of my routes work if I navigate when using that. I'm using lazy loading.

Comment: My app is not lazy loading. May be thats the difference.

Comment: @PhilipEnc Though maybe too late, this was exactly what I was looking for! I had a component that needed some plain js codes to run and when the component was destroyed and created again, those js codes would break. By keeping the states as this link implements, now everything's perfect :)