# Is it possible to prevent the destruction of Angular components when navigating?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

Assuming I have two Angular 2 components: `ComponentA` and `ComponentB`. 
I want to be able to navigate from ComponentA to ComponentB and then eventually back to ComponentA, while not having to reinitialize ComponentA.

In the current Angular 2 Router implementation, every time I navigate away from a component, the component gets destroyed and has to be recreated the next time I navigate to it.

I know that I can preserve the state of components by using a Service, but this seems to be more like a workaround than an actual solution to my issue. Is there any way around this?

Comment: See the links in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940095/angular2-routing-keeping-state-of-component-when-route-changes/36010817#36010817

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular

Comment: Hi Günter. Your link mentions `CanReuse` but I couldn't find it in the docs. Do you know if it still exists or if maybe it has been renamed?

Comment: @AngularFrance Apparently `CanReuse` was removed from the final version of Angular 2. To achieve a similar result, we can use the class `RouteReuseStrategy`, as also stated in the updated answer of Günter.

Comment: Ha, thanks! The search field on angular.io didn't yield any results when searching "reuse" (not event `RouteReuseStrategy`) so I couldn't find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement RouteReuseStrategy shouldDetach for specific routes in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is, you need to implement [RouteReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy).

and define a behavior for routes that reuse components.

Check more info in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515648/13112018