# RouteReuseStrategy in child module

Tags: angular, routes

here's my lazy loaded child module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(acnpRoutes),
    ....
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [
    {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: ACNPReuseStrategy}
  ]
})
export class AddCustomerNaturalPersonModule {
}
```

routes:

```
const acnpRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AddCustomerNaturalPersonComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'stepOne',
        component: ACNPStepOneComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'stepTwo',
        component: ACNPStepTwoComponent
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

And ACPNReuseStrategy:

```
export class ACNPReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  handlers: {[key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle} = {}

  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean  {
    console.log(1)
    return true;
  }

  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: {}): void {
    console.log(2)
  }

  ...

  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log(5)
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, none of these console.logs in ACNPReuseStrategy methods is fired. Why is that? Is reusing components possible in lazy loaded module?

Comment: shouldReuseRoute method should return boolean. Compare future and curr and return false if they are not equal.

Comment: Hi Jarosław, have you solved this issue and can share solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not...

Comment: @JarosławRewers I was able to use RouteReuseStrategy with lazy loaded module. You could check my implementation details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643748/angular-2-implementing-routereusestrategy?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR** provide your `RouteReuseStrategy` in main module instead of child module (`app.module.ts` by default). Then, assign each route a `key` in `route.data` to differentiate your routes.

---

I also encountered this issue recently. My child module is mounted under the main app routes like this:

```
..., {    // in app.route.ts
          path: 'apimarket',
          canActivate: [DeveloperResolve],
          loadChildren: './apimarket/apimarket.module#ApiMarketModule'
}
```

If I provide my customized `RouteReuseStrategy` in the child module `ApiMarketModule`, the `RouteReuseStrategy` will never be constructed.

The solution is to provide your Strategy in main module instead of child module (`app.module.ts` in my case). Then your `RouteReuseStrategy` will be constructed correctly.

However, the Strategy won't work as expected due to `route.routeConfig.path` is relative path because of your sub routes. To fix this, my solution is assign a unique `key` to my routes like this:

```
export const apimarketRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ApiMarketComponent,
        data: {
            shouldReuse: true,
            key: 'apimarketroot'
        }
    },
    {
        path: ':id',
        component: ContentPageComponent,
    }
];
```

Here is my `RouteReuseStrategy` implementation FYR

```
export class MyRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  handlers: {[key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle} = {};

  constructor() {
    console.log('constructed');
  }

  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    if (!route.data['shouldReuse']) {
      return null;
    }
    console.log('Attach cached page for: ', route.data['key']);
    return this.handlers[route.data['key']];
  }

  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    if (route.data['shouldReuse']) {
      this.handlers[route.data['key']] = handle;
    }
  }

  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return !!route.data['shouldReuse'];
  }

  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return !!route.data['shouldReuse'] && !!this.handlers[route.data['key']];
  }

  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, current: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return !!future.data['shouldReuse'];
  }
}
```

(`RouteReuseStrategy` isn't well documented, my solution may have potential performance issue due to the strategy working on root level. Welcome to discuss :) )

Comment: This is awesome and must be an accepted answer! It is still relevant today with `Angular 12.x`. My implementation was not working as expected until the `key` part I got to know from this answer. Once the `key` is added it is flawlessly working. Angular documentation is still poor after so may version releases. I hope to submitting a PR soon!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. You have noticed a significant issue with this feature. Everything just works so great now in my project.

Answer (score 3):

firstly,you must understand what are *future* and *curr*.eg: when you navigate from  *127.0.0.1:4200/a* to *127.0.0.1:4200/b* and now you are in b. the future is  *127.0.0.1:4200/a* ,curr is b，because the future  means that you will come back in the future.

when shouldReuseRoute return false ,future !== curr. that is to say the future is different from the curr,we need reuse the future in the future,then,the future will be detach , store and waiting to be reused. On the contrary, when it returns true, nothing is done because the future is the same as the curr.Imagine when you're in a, you want to go b,a is the future,b is the curr.A and b is the same thing, what is necessary to reuse, detach, store a?

Last,You have to understand the order in which these five methods are executed.
eg：

```
navigate to a
shouldReuseRoute->return true->do nothing

a->b
shouldReuseRoute()->return false->shouldDetach()->return true->store a

then b->a
shouldReuseRoute()->return false->shouldDetach()->return true->store b->retrieve() return a ->attach() a.
```

Be careful，when b->a,after shouldReuseRoute() return false,These methods are not strictly in the order above. For you to more easily understand this process, I deliberately writed so.But you still follow the above order to understand, this does not have any effect.

For better understanding, you should look at these examples. One of the examples will involve lazy loading.

https://medium.com/@gerasimov.pk/how-to-reuse-rendered-component-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy-64628e1ca3eb

[How to implement RouteReuseStrategy shouldDetach for specific routes in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular)

My English is not good,I hope you can understand what I said.