# How do I keep form state in Lazy Loading Module of Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I have build 2 route in my Angular 7 apps,

```
{
    path: 'create',
    component: CreateComponent
},
{
    path: 'view',
    component: ViewComponent
}
```

they are both **lazily loaded**, in `CreateComponent` there is a **form** with **many form fields** in it, and same thing happen with the `ViewComponent`.

The **problem** is, whenever i go to `/view` route or `ViewComponent` from `/create` route or `CreateComponent`, all of the form fields inside previous component (i.e. `ViewComponent`) were returned to initial state (i check it by returning to `/create` route again), in other word the form fields got automatically reset, and the same thing happened if I went from `/view` route to `/create` route, all the form fields in `/view` were reset by angular automatically.

So, how to fix this problem? I want to keep all the form fields keep its previous value (even though the form weren't submitted yet) if i change or go to another routes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Main thing to note here, When you navigate away angular component destroyed then navigate back it is recreated again. There are several ways to maintain component data.

1. [Use services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#why-services) to store the data and reuse when component initialised again -
2. Store data in local storage and reuse when component initialised again
3. [RouteReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy). This provide mechanism to reuse angular components. Note that this wouldn't work with sibling router outlets. May be, I couldn't make it work for sibling routes. You can refer to my previous answer related to implementing [RouteReUseStrategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643748/angular-2-implementing-routereusestrategy?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with lazy loading,
e.g assuming you are using reactive controls in your form,

```
userForm: FormGroup
constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {}
ngOnInIt() {
 this.userForm = this.fb.group({
 firstName: [null, Validators.required],
 lastName: [null, Validators.required]
});
}
```

Whenever you reload this component, first Lifecycle hook which is called is ngOnInIt() {}
so your form will be again reinitialized, storing the value of firstName and lastName as null.

Solution: Create a new Class

```
export class User {
firstName: string,
lastName: string

constructor (data) {
  this.firstName = data.firstName ? data.firstName : '';
  this.lastName = data.lastName ? data.lastName : '';
 }
}
```

Using Above Class to create a reactive control.
if you have stored your user data somewhere fetch it via services create a new user and pass the same to controls.

```
userForm: FormGroup
user: User
constructor(private someService: SomeService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInIt() {
 //get User some random function which makes an api call and fetches user data 
 //if available else returns {} 
 this.someService.getUser((res) => {
  this.user = new User(res);
  this.createForm();
 });
}

createForm() {
 this.userForm = this.fb.group({
  firstName: [this.user.firstName, Validators.required],
  lastName: [this.user.lastName, Validators.required]
})
}
```

//with user = new User(res);
if there is a res.firstName field in it it will add it to user else will set it as the empty string.

Hope this helps, this should fix the issue