# Angular Cannot reattach ActivatedRouteSnapshot with a different number of children

Tags: angular, angular-router, nativescript-angular

Here is my routing in a nativescript-angular project:

```js
const routes: Routes = [

    {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "/tabs/default",
        pathMatch: "full"
    },
    {
        path: "tabs",
        loadChildren: "~/app/modules/tabs/tabs.module#TabsModule"
    },
    {
        path: "login",
        loadChildren: "~/app/modules/login/login.module#LoginModule"
    },
    {
        path: "register",
        loadChildren: "~/app/modules/register/register.module#RegisterModule"
    }

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
        preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
    })],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
```

The scenario which leads to the error: First the app starts with tabs route, then I go to the login page, after that I go to register and then again I go to tabs page (and clean the history). After that if I go to login page again and get back to previous one (tabs page), the error occurs.

The error:

```
JS: Error: Cannot reattach ActivatedRouteSnapshot with a different number of children
JS:     at setFutureSnapshotsOfActivatedRoutes (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.tns57/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:1950:19) [angular]
JS:     at setFutureSnapshotsOfActivatedRoutes (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.tns57/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:1954:13) [angular]
JS:     at createNode (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.tns57/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:1935:17) [angular]
JS:     at file:///data/data/org.nativescript.tns57/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:1975:20 [angular]
JS:     at Array.map (<anonymous>) [angular]
JS:     at createOrReuseChildren (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.tns57/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:1958:30) [angular]
JS:     at createNode (file:///data/data/org...
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try without cleanHistory ?

Comment: @Narendra Still I get the error wihtout `clearHistory`.

Comment: @Narendra You can test with this repo: https://github.com/NativeScript/login-tab-navigation-ng/issues/7

Comment: do you use `RouterModule.forRoot` to initialize this or `this.router.resetConfig` ? can you please add the section of the module where you use this array?

Comment: @Thatkookooguy I use `forRoot` to initialize. Updated the content. Please see again. Thanks.

Comment: @VahidNajafi Are you using RouteReuseStrategy? Can you share your implementation?

Comment: @nayakam No, I don't use `RouteReuseStrategy` at all. (just tested the one in the answer and it didn't work)

Comment: Hav you tried removing the preloading strategy to see if it works without it ?

Comment: @Maryannah The main repo doesn't contain the preloading strategy at all: https://github.com/NativeScript/login-tab-navigation-ng/blob/master/src/app/app-routing.module.ts

Comment: @VahidNajafi Can you update the playground https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=HYGiOH to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try change the first route

```
{
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "tabs",
    pathMatch: "full"
}
```

and set your `TabsModule` like that

```
const routes: Routes = [    
    {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "default",
        pathMatch: "full"
    },
    {
        path: "default",
        component: YourDefaultComponent
    }
    ...
];
```

**UPDATE :** If you get an same error, you can use `AttachDetachReuseStrategy`

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouteReuseStrategy, DetachedRouteHandle } from '@angular/router';

interface RouteStorageObject {
    snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
    handle: DetachedRouteHandle;
}

export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {


    handlers: { [key: string]: RouteStorageObject } = {};

    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
        if (!route.routeConfig) return null;
        if (route.routeConfig.loadChildren) return null;
        return this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
    }

    .....

}
```

then I make `shouldDetach` function also check for loadChildren to prevent `RouteReuseStrategy` save wrong `ActivatedRouteSnapshot:`

```
shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    if (!route.routeConfig || route.routeConfig.loadChildren) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Ofcourse, modify your `AppModule`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    providers: [
        {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomReuseStrategy}
    ],
    ....
)}
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still, I get the same error.

Comment: You mean I must have a `CustomReuseStrategy` and add it to my providers?

Comment: What is `this.handlers`? Where do you define it?

Comment: I did it. But the result is the following: Tabs get loaded first, then I go to login page, the from login I go to register. Then I come back, in login animations reinitialize (this shouldn't be done when I press back button) , then I press back again to go back to tabs, now content of tabs disapear.

Comment: I used `retrieve` and `shouldDetach` as you mentioned, and for `store` I do nothing, for `shouldAttach` I return false, and for `shouldReuseRoute` I return `future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;`. Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to `nativescript-angular` to version 7.2.4 . The repo link that you [posted](https://github.com/NativeScript/login-tab-navigation-ng/blob/master/package.json) is using version 7.2.3 that contains some issue with routing.

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/pull/1740

Comment: Thanks. But I still get the same error after updating `nativescript-angular` to version 7.2.4. Could you be able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: is it possible for you to create the playground?

Comment: @VahidNajafi Have you tried disabling Route Resue by adding this
`import {Router} from "@angular/router";`
`this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function(){ return false;};`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing the relativeTo extras? Weirdly this worked for me and I can't figure out how and why.

```
this.routerExtension.back({relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
```

Like this.