# ngrx/store not showing the updated values of a form

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I need to enter 2 input values that shows the Usage of a storage space in megabytes (used_space and remaining_space) via a form and show  the entered values from ngrx/Store. Each time the form is submitted the new values are showed and the old ones are updated. The problem is that the UI shows always the default values of (used_space and remaining_space) and I do not know if my architecture is right since I am new in ngrx/store.

Model (usage.model.ts):

```
   export interface Usage {
      used_space: number;
      remaining_space: number;
    }
```

Actions (usage.actions.ts):

```
export const EDIT_USAGE  = '[Usage] Edit';
...
export class EditUsage implements Action {
  readonly type = EDIT_USAGE
  constructor(public payload: Usage) {}
}
...
export type All = Reset | EditUsage;
```

Reducer (usage.reducer.ts):
    export type Action = UsageActions.All;

```
/// Default app state
const defaultState: Usage = {
  used_space: 2,
  remaining_space: 3
}

/// Helper function to create new state object
const newState = (state, newData) => {
  return Object.assign({}, state, newData)
}

export function usageReducer(state: Usage = defaultState, action: Action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case UsageActions.EDIT_USAGE:
      // return [...state, action.payload];
      return newState(state, { Usage: action.payload });
    case UsageActions.RESET:
      return defaultState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

In app.component.ts:

```
  usage: Observable<Usage>

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.usage = this.store.select('usage')
  }

  editUsage(used_space,remaining_space) {
    this.store.dispatch(new UsageActions.EditUsage({used_space:used_space , remaining_space:remaining_space}) )
  }
```

In app.component.html:

```
<input type="text"  #used_space>
<input type="text"  #remaining_space>
<button (click)="editUsage(used_space.value,remaining_space.value)" >Edit Space</button>

<div *ngIf="usage | async as u">
  <h2>Used space: {{ u.used_space }}</h2>
  <h2>remaining space: {{ u.remaining_space }}</h2>
</div>
```

I am not seeing any result and I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: Did you register the reducer in your `app.module.ts`?

Comment: yes it is already registered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your `reducer`:

```
switch(action.type) {
  case UsageActions.EDIT_USAGE:
    return newState(state, { Usage: action.payload }); <<--------
}
```

you are passing previous state and a **`new object with usage as a property`**. What `Object.assign` does is: create a new object, append previous state to it, attach a brand new property `Usage` and add new values of store to that. Here's view of newly created object:

[image]

You can solve this passing the `payload` directly:

```
switch(action.type) {
  case UsageActions.EDIT_USAGE:
    return newState(state, action.payload);
}
```

[**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrq9wn)

Plus, as long as you are updating object as whole in your reducer, I believe you don't need `Object.assign()` too. You can directly return the `action.payload` as it is the new state.

Comment: thanks a lot for the proposal it works like a charm.. :)

Comment: there is still an issue with your solution: the data entered in the form disappears after router changing.  Do you have a clue about the reason behind this?

Comment: can u try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755383/how-to-keep-form-data-when-switching-tabs-routes)?

Comment: I saw the link and I will try it. But I think it is not safe to have access to the service directly from the UI component, there should be a kind of controller in between (the component .ts file for example) so that services are not exposed. Anyway I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the selector.

`this.store.select('usage')`

It will work if you have a object named `usage` inside your store.

For example:

```
const defaultState: AppState = {
  usage: {
    used_space: 2,
    remaining_space: 3
  }
}
```

So your code should be

```
// Default app state
const defaultState: AppState = {
  usage: {
    used_space: 2,
    remaining_space: 3
  }
}

export function usageReducer(state: AppState = defaultState, action: Action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case UsageActions.EDIT_USAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        usage: action.payload
      }

    case UsageActions.RESET:
      return defaultState;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I already have defined default value in the reducer

Comment: The form entered values are received in the app.component.ts but the showed value is always the default value..please is there any help here?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in my reply. I would explain that there is a incoherence in your code. defaultState should be AppState type. And then inside an object usage. It's the case inside your EDIT_ACTION, return is ok. But defaultState is not.

Comment: so I created "add.state.ts" file:  'interface AppState {
  usage: Usage;
}'  , then I import the AppState inside the reducer. After that apply the code changes you suggested, is that right?

Comment: I tried what I mentioned above but still not working.. do you know an example showing similar requirements: update only one object containing 2 values without the need for collection of objects? or even can I use 2 variables (used_space and remaining_space) of type 'number' without wrapping them inside an object and update them via ngrx/store?