# how do i update the ngrx store - when button click in angular UI

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

Lets us assume i have the following data in ngrx/store

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "containers": [
    {
      "id": 1.1,
      "x": 10,
      "y": 40
    },
    {
      "id": 1.2,
      "x": 40,
      "y": 30
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the code in the Ui

```
<button type="button" (click)='onclick(x, y)'></button>

 onclick(x, y){

   // For example if the value x and y are 20 and 20 then i want the update the json in ngrx store like this

{
  "id": 1,
  "containers": [
    {
      "id": 1.1,
      "x": 20, 
      "y": 20
    },
    {
      "id": 1.2,
      "x": 20,
      "y": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

}

How can i achieve this result so i can update the same in ngrx store

Comment: Please try with https://stackoverflow.com/a/50856837/8213994 this solution

Comment: You need to create one action for update the value as per above example